# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value' to plot a chart

Tags: python, pandas

I need to plot a chart but it raises the following error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6816/1118115357.py in <module>
      5     plt.show()
      6 
----> 7 plot_df(df, x=df.index, y=df.value, title='Mecerdez Car Sales in the US from 2015 to 2020.')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize': (10, 7), 'figure.dpi': 120})
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv('TS.csv', parse_dates = ['date'], index_col = 'date')

def plot_df(df, x, y, title="", xlabel='Date', ylabel='Sales', dpi=100):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,5), dpi=dpi)
    plt.plot(x, y, color='tab:red')
    plt.gca().set(title=title, xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel)
    plt.show()

plot_df(df, x=df.index, y=df.value, title='Mecerdez Car Sales in the US from 2015 to 2020.')
```

DataFrame:

```
    Sales
date    
2015-01-01  6236.0
2015-01-02  7072.0
2015-01-03  7635.0
2015-01-04  6665.0
2015-01-05  7413.0
```

Comment: you called `df.value` but your column is named Sales. Therefore you should replace it with `df.Sales`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
plot_df(df, x=df.index, y=df['Sales'], title='Mecerdez Car Sales in the US from 2015 to 2020.')
```